# Sparta.py fails because it cannot import python-elixir

Tags: python, linux, security

I'm trying to run sparta.py in the latest distribution of Kali linux. However when I do so I get the following error:

```
[-] Import failed. Elixir library not found. 
Try installing it with: apt install python-elixir
```

In response to the above I ran `sudo apt install python-elixir` and subsequently got:

```
E: Package 'python-elixir' has no installation candidate
```

I'm stuck - I've tried using pip and I've even tried a manual install but still cannot find anyone else experiencing this problem.

How do I solve the "Elixir library not found" error?

Comment: What's sparta.py ? Is that the entire output?

Answer (score 0):

You can find `sparta` by name `legion` in Kali Linux. Do:

`# apt install legion`

And get you software package.